# Get the total number of letters in a text

Tags: java, selenium

I have to extract to total number of letters in this following example.

```
<div data-v-2f952c88="" class="text">
 <section data-v-3b70ad5b="" data-v-2f952c88="" data-content-provider="ABC" class="description__section"><!---->
   <div data-v-051a83e7="" data-v-3b70ad5b="" class="markdown" data-v-2f952c88="">
     <p>Headline 1<br>
       This is my first example</p>
     <p> Another Text
        this is onother example
     </p>
   </div>
 </section>
 <section data-v-3b70ad5b="" data-v-2f952c88="" data-content-provider="DEF" class="description__section">
     <div data-v-051a83e7="" data-v-3b70ad5b="" class="markdown" data-v-2f952c88="">
        <p>Headline 2<br>
            Java Rocks</p>
        <p> Another Text
            Selenium also rocks
        </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

How can I extract all the letters inside the several tags "p" that are under several tags "section"?

Comment: You can use `driver.find_elements`  https://www.guru99.com/find-element-selenium.html

Comment: in that case i can only extract one text from one "p" i need to extract from several "p" and "sections"

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to iterate throught all elements something like this(didn´t look the java syntasys but adapt it for yourself jus take the idea)

```
foreach(IwebElement element in driver.findElements(By.Tag("p"))){
    //Work with the element.Text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
    String[] tags = {"p", "section"};
    int totalLetters = 0;
    for (String tag: tags) {
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName(tag));
        for (WebElement element: elements) {
            totalLetters = totalLetters + element.getText().length();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

how are you? well... first of all do you read something about HTML [DOM?](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

in Javascript Using DOM you can do something like this:

```
var myCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

Next you will have something like an collection of "p" tags

You can access them by index number: `y = myCollection[1];` or loop it:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myCollection.length; i++) {
  //do something with myCollection...
}
```

Your example can look something like:

```js
var myCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var i;
var added = 0;
for (i = 0; i < myCollection.length; i++) {
   added += myCollection[i].innerText.length;
}
alert(added);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div data-v-2f952c88="" class="text">
 <section data-v-3b70ad5b="" data-v-2f952c88="" data-content-provider="ABC" class="description__section"><!---->
   <div data-v-051a83e7="" data-v-3b70ad5b="" class="markdown" data-v-2f952c88="">
     <p>Headline 1<br>
       This is my first example</p>
     <p> Another Text
        this is onother example
     </p>
   </div>
 </section>
 <section data-v-3b70ad5b="" data-v-2f952c88="" data-content-provider="DEF" class="description__section">
     <div data-v-051a83e7="" data-v-3b70ad5b="" class="markdown" data-v-2f952c88="">
        <p>Headline 2<br>
            Java Rocks</p>
        <p> Another Text
            Selenium also rocks
        </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
I hope you find it useful!
```

Comment: Que tengas un buen día Bruno!